# How to get conda activate to work with csh?

Tags: conda, csh

I installed anaconda distribution.

The `conda activate someEnv name` is not working.

I get the error

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate`.
To initialie your shell, run
    $conda init <SHELL_NAME>
Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
```

How can I get `conda activate someEnvName` to work with csh?

Comment: which conda version do you have? csh should be supported, see [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3176)

Comment: You use tcsh
tcsh is advanced version.
csh itself is two much old, so some sys calls tcsh as csh.
Try find difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me on CentOS 7

from bash:

```
conda init tcsh
```

conda creates/edits ~/.tcshrc which is sourced when I log in with csh.

add the following line to the end of .tcsrc if you still want to source your .cshrc

```
source .cshrc
```